# Atom doesn't install packages on Mint

Tags: linux-mint, atom

I'm using Mint 19.1 Tessa. I've installed Atom 1.38 and I can't install any packages on it, bot using wizard inside IDE and in terminal usin `apm`. Any ideas what might be the problem and how to fix it?